# wxPython: using SetHint in wx.TextEntryDialog

Tags: python-3.x, modal-dialog, wxpython

I have the following class that creates a `wx.TextEntryDialog` with a default value in the text control. However, I would like to show the text value as `SetHint` does because the initial value is just an example of the expected input. Right now, users need to delete the entire initial text, with `SetHint` this is automatically done when users start typing.

Is there a way to do this? Right now, I cannot access the text control in the dialog to use `SetHint`.

```
class DlgTextInput(wx.TextEntryDialog):
    """ Creates a Text Input Dialog """

    def __init__(self, parent, message, value='', caption=''):
        """ message: msg to show """
        if caption == '':
            super().__init__(parent, message, value=value)
        else:
            super().__init__(parent, message, value=value, caption=caption)
        self.Center()
    #---
#---
```

Comment: On Linux, at least, the `value` is selected, so pressing any key immediately wipes it out. So on your OS is there a different behaviour?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Yes, in macOS with wxPython 4.0.4, users need to select the entire text, then delete it and finally start typing. That is why I made my own custom class so I can use SetHint on the TextCtrl.